# What's a good book title for Op-Amp design?

Tags: operational-amplifier, design

I already have *OpAmps for everyone* but like many electronics texts, it describes what they are,how they work, what they do, and how to use them as components in circuits(monolithic op-amp ICs) but doesn't go in depth about the internals of an individual op-amp and how to actually design an op-amp oneself! That's what I'm looking for: A book that describes in detail the op-amp microelectronic circuit design down to the transistor level! In particular because I'm seeking to design one and first test it with discrete transistors.

Comment: What you are looking for is part of *analog IC design*.  Look around in IC design literature, not circuit design.

Comment: Actually, I'm not talking about designing an analog IC. But an op-amp circuit with discrete transistors. I said that already.

Comment: There is very limited need for a discrete component op-amp in product designs because the thermal coupling on the die is far better than any thermal coupling of individual discrete components. This coupling allows for compensation so the properties of the op-amp don't drift with temperature. Other things are also much better controlled like parasitic capacitance which affect bandwidth etc.

Comment: Making a opamp from discrete parts makes little sense.  A opamp is a generic building block.  It benefits from all being on one die, but has to be generic because it could be used lots of ways.  You might build a amplifier for your particular purpose from discrete transistors, but making a general purpose building block, then using it a specific way doesn't make much sense when you can design the discrete circuit to do exactly what you want in the first place.  You don't need to produce a million of them to make economic sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several books that deal with the design of op amps.

A notable classic is

P. R. Gray, P. J. Hurst, S. H. Lewis, R. G. Meyer, *Analysis and Design of Analog Integrated Circuits*. 5th ed.,  Wiley, 2009 ([Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470245999)).

Another one I like, quite recent, is

S. Franco, *Analog Circuit Design: Discrete & Integrated*, McGraw-Hill Education, 2014 ([Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0078028191)).

Comment: The designer of the famous NE555, Hans Camenzind has written an Ebook which you can download for free. Find it here: http://www.designinganalogchips.com Some part of the book is about opamp circuits.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Ah, yes, that's a good one too, I forgot about it!